# Is Java in android studio exactly same with normal Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning Java and Android Studio now. It might be a silly question But I'm just wondering if Java in Android Studio is exactly the same as Standard Java.
I just learned that we use ids for calling views in Android Studio
and is normal Java has the same concept as Android Studio?
Or we can say Java in Android Studio is a little different version of Java?

Comment: All the concepts of Core Java is same but in Android you use inbuilt classes specific for android

Comment: I will suggest you read more about java. When you are good then move to android stuff. Then you will know about this question. Else it will be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Java platform has different editions.
J2SE - standard edition, this is also known as Core Java. It contains a variety of general-purpose APIs and many special-purpose APIs.
This is mainly used for creating desktop applications.

J2ME - Micro edition, this version is mainly used for building applications that run on embedded systems like mobiles. It uses many libraries of J2SE and many of its own.

J2EE - Enterprise edition, is a community-driven edition. This is used in creating web pages and web services.

And the java we use in the android studio is a micro edition to develop mobile applications.
[For further reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/j2se-vs-j2me-vs-j2ee-whats-the-difference/)

Answer (score -3):

No,My friend All the concepts those are in core java are used in android studio with predefined classes name.
Such as Editext is class while SetOnclicklistener is an interface.
Thus language is same but wrapped under convention in android